# Why is my jquery/javascript not working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

so I have this javascript/jquery to make a delay before showing a swf file, but its not working, when I say not working, I mean it does nothing...

Here is the script:

```
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" ></script>
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

<script>
function Func1()
{
$('#stage').html("<OBJECT style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:20%; left:44%;" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" id="rice" ALIGN="">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="rice.swf"> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399> <EMBED src="rice.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" NAME="rice" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED> </OBJECT>");
}

function Func1Delay()
{
setTimeout("Func1()", 10000);
}

</script>
```

Here is how I am calling the function:

```
<body onload="Func1Delay()" >
```

It seems to be doing absolutley nothing... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your double quotes are all mis-matched. Also, `"Func1()"` should be `Func1`

Comment: change the first and last " inside `html("")` to ' - you're closing the string with `style="`

Comment: Did you make any attempt other to c/p [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974724/show-image-then-swf) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to escape the `"` in the object tag or else you'll get syntax errors

```
$('#stage').html("<OBJECT style=\"z-index:2; position:absolute; top:20%; left:44%;\" classid=\"clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000\" codebase=\"http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0\" WIDTH=\"320\" HEIGHT=\"240\" id=\"rice\" ALIGN=\"\">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE=\"rice.swf\"> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399> <EMBED src=\"rice.swf\" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH=\"320\" HEIGHT=\"240\" NAME=\"rice\" ALIGN=\"\" TYPE=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" PLUGINSPAGE=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\"></EMBED> </OBJECT>");
```

Also according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) using a string of code fot setTimeout is not recommended. use `setTimeout(Func1, 10000);` instead.

Comment: Or even better, use single quotes to surround the string in the `.html` function instead of double quotes.

Comment: also, put 'type' in with your script tags: <script type="text/javascript" src="...etc..">

Comment: @Snowsickle, that depends on how anal you are regarding HTML syntax.

Comment: @burmat that depends on whether or not you're using HTML5 since in html5 the type attribute is optional.

Comment: @Casey, I was referring to changing the double quotes surrounding the object tag to single quotes, not the ones within the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

An onload attribute is a terribly dated method for executing JavaScript at runtime, especially if you're using jQuery.

```
$().ready({ function(){
    // set you timeout here
});
```

Also, your JavaScript is laden with errors.  You need to escape the quotes in the HTML you're trying to embed.  You've got text just floating between strings as it is now, so that's definitely throwing some syntax errors.

```
$('#stage').html("<OBJECT style=\"z-index:2; position:absolute; top:20%; left:44%;\" // and so on.
```

In addition, I think the syntax for setTimeout is wrong in your code too.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
setTimeout("Func1()", 10000);
```

to:

```
setTimeout(Func1, 10000);
```

Comment: really???  Remove the quotes and then yeah, okay.  It will still work the way he originally did it.

Comment: cmon guys it's obviously a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your script tags have a 'type' and use single quotes for your HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" ></script>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Do 'onload' here:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Func1Delay();
    });

    function Func1() {
        $('#stage').html('<OBJECT style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:20%; left:44%;" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" id="rice" ALIGN=""><PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="rice.swf"> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399> <EMBED src="rice.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" NAME="rice" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED> </OBJECT>');
    }

    function Func1Delay() {
        setTimeout(Func1, 10000);
    }
</script>
```